# Does Noore's Fortress have a trading post and if so, where is it?

Tags: far-cry-4

I just took over Noore's Fortress, but I can't find the usual bedroom / trading post (the one indicated by a red door).  **Does the fortress have one, and if so where is it?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it.  It's upstairs, to the left as you walk into the main hall.